# Input Text field with comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have a input text field which users can input a number and for a currency.

```
<input type="text" name="com-uprice" value="">
```

I used this snippet to add a comma for every 3 digits

```
        $('input[name="com-uprice"]').keyup(function(event) {

          // skip for arrow keys
          if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

          // format number
          $(this).val(function(index, value) {
            return value
            .replace(/\D/g, "")
            .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
            console.log(this.val)
          });
        });
```

Now I need that value into a number for computation purposes
I used this line of code to convert it into a number

```
parseInt($('input[name="com-uprice"]').val().replace(',', ''))
```

It returns a number but not the whole number that users inputted.

For example.
If I input `1,000,000`
It returns like `1000` only

Comment: .replace(/,/g,'')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace function only replaces first occurance of the given string. You can use below snippets.

```
parseInt($('input[name="com-uprice"]').val().split(',').join(''))

parseInt($('input[name="com-uprice"]').val().replace(/,/g, '')
```

(Starting from chrome v85)

```
parseInt($('input[name="com-uprice"]').val().replaceAll(',', '')
```

Comment: You are welcome :)) You can check it as answer if that is okay.